# Make ternary operator return an empty/ignored item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to construct a list with one optional element based on a condition.  As an example, I want `['a','b','c','d','e']` if `has_b==True`, and `['a','c','d','e']` if `has_b==False`.  What should I do if I want to use a ternary expression:  `['a', ('b' if has_b else ???),'c','d','e']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
['a','b','c','d','e'] if has_b else ['a','c','d','e']
```

or

```
['a'] + (['b'] if has_b else []) + ['c','d','e']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
['a'] + (['b'] if has_b else []) + ['c','d','e']
```